Existence of Nash Equilibrium in a Game with Mixed Strategy Spaces
I am considering formulating an applied research problem as a simultaneous zero-sum game with two players. The first player's set of actions is an infinite and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, while the second player has a finite number of actions. For a specific action $s_2$ chosen by Player 2,
I am aware of the result stating that if the set of choices for each player were compact and the payoff function were continuous in the strategies of all players, then a (mixed) Nash Equilibrium would exist. However, since Player 2's actions are discrete, this result does not apply directly to my case.
Are there any results that might guarantee the existence of a Nash Equilibrium under perhaps a few additional conditions for problems like mine? I have struggled to find relevant information on this topic in my searches.

On your statment:

I am aware of the result stating that if the set of choices for each player were compact and the payoff function were continuous in the strategies of all players, then a (mixed) Nash Equilibrium would exist. However, since Player 2's actions are discrete, this result does not apply directly to my case.

This statment is not correct. In fact, we have the following two key results:
Result 1: A static (strategic-form) game has a pure-strategy Nash equilibrium if

the strategy sets are compact and convex
the utility functions are continuous on the strategy sets
the utility function of each player is quasi-concave in the player's strategy, when the other players' strategies are fixed.

Result 2: A static game has a (pure-strategy or mixed-strategy) Nash equilibrium when the strategy sets are finite.
The game in the OP is called infinite  zero-sum two-person game, in which the strategy set of one player is infinite. These games may have no equilibrium. You can find many intresting results and examples on such games in this note. When, one player has a finite strategy set, it is called semi-finite game; see Theorem 7.1 for a sufficient condition.

I recall that any finite topological space is compact and any function on a discrete topological space is continuous. I hope that then in your problem the payoff function is continuous in the strategies of all players, and so a (mixed) Nash Equilibrium exists.
